# How to get specific portion of timeseries and add it to the previous timeseries step?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series

I have a dataset that contains variables for an industrial plant. These variables are pressure, temperature and flowrate. They are differenced in order to be stationary.

```
                              Flow        T_2            P_1
Datetime
        
2019-03-12 09:30:01+00:00   109.280853  -0.002633    0.000260
2019-03-12 09:30:02+00:00   -97.592285   0.010860    0.000271
2019-03-12 09:30:03+00:00    32.246445   0.001354   -0.000980
2019-03-12 09:30:04+00:00    -9.779053  -0.019827   -0.000538
2019-03-12 09:30:05+00:00   -58.054190   0.023431    0.001198
```

The total number of observations is nearly 20 thousand. I have made a for loo where I utilize the pd.Grouper in order to get a specified
time interval, within which I run a machine learning algorithm and I save the results as a picture.

The loop starts like this:

`for name,group in dataset.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = "10min"):`

Every time I run a the loop, I get results for every consecutive 10 minutes. I want to modify the algorithm in order to get the first 10 minutes, then 20 minutes, then thirty minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to iteratively concatenate the groups with a new data frame.

For example:

```
accumulated_groups = pd.DataFrame()
for name,group in dataset.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = "10min"):
    accumulated_groups = pd.concat(accumulated_groups, group)
```